# Filter and merge in ffmpeg at once

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to do several modifications on video files at once.

I need to add an intro and outro video snippet to the input video. So this means merging 3 videos.
I need to add an overlay image to the input video (the second segment) and only that.
How can I combine these to one line?

I managed to do these in two steps. First the overlay:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i image.png -filter_complex overlay=main_w-overlay_w-0:0 output_file.mkv
```

Then the merging:

```
ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -i input.mkv -i outro.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[video_out][audio_out]" -map "[video_out]" -map "[audio_out]" output_file.mkv
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: It's there. I tried those two command and those work. I just would like to combine these to one command.

Comment: Yes, I am aware. I am asking what you tried regarding this task of merging, if anything. Combining 2 filtergraphs is not something very complex, especially if you wrote the 2 commands yourself, which would mean you have some basic udnerstanding. These kind of "pls combine my X ffmpeg filter_complex commands" questions are  not productive, as it can be seen, as there are tons of these still appearing, which means they're not too helpful for people to stop tons of them appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use temporary naming `[v1]` for the output of `overlay=main_w-overlay_w-0:0` then use `[v1]` as input to the `concat` filter:

`ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -i input.mkv -i outro.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex "[1:v][3:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-0:0[v1];[0:v:0][0:a:0][v1][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[video_out][audio_out]" -map "[video_out]" -map "[audio_out]" output_file.mkv`

---

- The following part applies the overlay stage:
  `[1:v][3:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-0:0[v1]`
  The ovelayed output gets the temporary name `[v1]`.
- `[0:v:0][0:a:0][v1][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0]concat`
  uses `[v1]` as input to `concat` (instead of `[1:v:0]`).

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly!